# Transform a number of islands into a number of countries solution in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, ecmascript-6, depth-first-search

The original problem says that it should be counted the number of islands (connected entities of 1 into a sea of 0).

For example:

```
0001
1001
0110
```

should return 3 becasue there are 3 islands.

I managed to get a solution to this:

```
function countIslands(A) {
    const row = A.length;
    const col = A[0].length;
    
    const search = (row, col, A) => {
        if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row > A.length - 1 || col > A[row].length - 1 || A[row][col] === 0) {
            return;
        }
        A[row][col] = 0;
        search(row-1,col,A);
        search(row,col-1,A);
        search(row+1,col,A);
        search(row,col+1,A);
    }
    let count = 0;
    A.forEach((row, index) => {
        row.forEach((value, indexI) => {
            if(value === 1) {
                search(index, indexI, A);
                count++;
            }
        })
    })
    return count;
}
```

it works fine. But is it a way to change it (ideally not a lot of changes) to make it able to count countries?

For example:

```
1122
1223
5521
```

should return 5 because there are 5 entities in the matrix.

Comment: How did you get 3 for the first example? I got 4

Comment: it's 3. copy the code and test it with this: `countIslands([[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0]]);`

Comment: I don't mean I got it through your code. I mean shouldn't it be 4?

Comment: no, there are 3 islands: top right corner there are two 1s, middle row left - there is one 1, bottom row, there are two 1s. So 3 islands in total. And when I test it in code it's correct: it returns 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hand over the actual value and look only for adjacent same values.

I add some visualation for the found islands/countries.

```js
function countIslands(A) {
    const row = A.length;
    const col = A[0].length;

    const search = (row, col, A, value) => {
        if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= A.length || col >= A[row].length || A[row][col] !== value) {
            return;
        }
        A[row][col] = 0;
        search(row - 1, col, A, value);
        search(row, col - 1, A, value);
        search(row + 1, col, A, value);
        search(row, col + 1, A, value);
    }
    let count = 0;
    A.forEach((row, index) => {
        row.forEach((value, indexI) => {
            if (value !== 0) {

                A.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
                console.log('');

                search(index, indexI, A, value);
                count++;
            }
        })
    })
    A.forEach(a => console.log(...a))
    return count;
}

console.log(countIslands([[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3], [5, 5, 2, 1]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think that your solution solves a different problem. My question is about countries=each different connected entity. There is no "sea" anymore. Any connected set of same numbers is a country like in the example at the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your recursive approach, you can solve this in a single sweep from top left to bottom right.

It creates an array of unique identifiers for each new found territory.
`value !== empty && value !== left && value !== top`

keeps track to which ID the current cell belongs (by index in the `indices` array)

and "merges" the IDs for instances where `value === left && value === top` (two indices contain at the same ID)

so that the `number of unique IDS` === `number of distinct territories` in this map.

```js
function replace(array, oldValue, newValue) {
  //console.log("replace", oldValue, newValue);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] === oldValue) array[i] = newValue
  }
  return newValue;
}

function countIslands(rows, empty = "0") {
  let prev = []; // previous row to determine the top value
  const indices = []; // may contain differrent indices that point to the same ID
  const ids = []; // initially unique IDS, will contain dupes when IDs get "merged"

  for (let row of rows) {
    for (let i = 0; i < row.length; ++i) {
      const value = row[i];
      if (value === empty) {
        continue;
      }
      // current cell is not "empty"

      const top = prev[i] || empty;
      const left = row[i - 1] || empty;

      if (value === left && value === top) {
        // merge ids (think an u-shape where you started at two ends, not knowing in advance that they will meet)
        indices[i] = replace(ids, indices[i - 1], indices[i]);
      } else if (value === left) {
        // current cell belongs to left cell, copy the index
        indices[i] = indices[i - 1];
      } else if (value !== top) {
        // new country, create new id
        indices[i] = ids.length;
        ids[ids.length] = ids.length; // doesn't matter, as long as it is unique.
      }
    }
    prev = row;
  }

  //the number of countries === number of distinct IDs left. 
  return new Set(ids).size;
}
// 9
const map = `
777788
711227
712237
755217
887777`;

/*
// this is as intertwined as it gets, 
// 2 spirals
const map = `
3333333333
2222222223
2333333323
2322222323
2323332323
2323232323
2323222323
2323333323
2322222223
2333333333`;
*/

console.log(countIslands(map.trim().split("\n").map(row => [...row.trim()])));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```